# How to have Screen Sharing + Firewall without port 5900 open in OS X

Tags: macos, security, firewall, vncserver

On 10.6.8, if you have both Screen Sharing and Firewall turned on, port 5900 is automatically opened in the firewall.  This is bad, because I want to access that port via ssh port forwarding and not allow it open to the world.

When I go into Sharing, Computer Settings there's nothing, and in the Advanced... Firewall settings I can't disallow incoming connections for "Screen Sharing".

I can also connect directly to the machine with VNC and port 5900.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Solution is:

```
ipfw -f flush
ipfw add 10000 allow ip from any to any via lo0
ipfw add 20000 deny ip from any to any dst-port 5900 in
```

After the above, I can access port 5900 via port forwarding, but not directly from outside the machine.

Comment: "IPFW was deprecated in OS X 10.7, and was completely removed in OS X 10.10; it was replaced with PF." —https://pleiades.ucsc.edu/hyades/PF_on_Mac_OS_X

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to override it by adding your own `ipfw` firewall rule to block port 5900. Start with `man ipfw` and go from there.

Comment: I expected "ipfw -a list" to show the current state of the firewall, but apparently the Firewall app doesn't use ipfw.  Weird.

Comment: @e40 You're right, the default "application firewall" doesn't use `ipfw`. I think the strict firewall still did in Snow Leopard though. And when you go to Lion or Mountain Lion, you'll discover that `ipfw` has been deprecated in favor of `pf`.

Comment: Crikey!  I'll have to read up on `pf`.  Thanks.